# PHP echo anchor link not working

Tags: php, echo, anchor

I'm trying to echo a link on a page. It should be a bootstrap button, but it's just coming out as plain text.

This is my code. What am I doing wrong?

```
echo '<a class="btn btn-info" href='.$url.'>Video Link</a>';
```

Comment: try `echo '<a class="btn btn-info" href="'.$url.'">Video Link</a>';` Need to wrap the url with `"`

Comment: how have you initialized the value for `$url` variable??

Comment: `but it's just coming out as plain text.` I cannot replicate this issue. Make sure you actually have a linked CSS. Check dev tools (F12) and look at debugger - it should tell you if it cannot find the css

Comment: @RakibulIslam I have checked by echoing just the variable and it is working.

Comment: @IsThisJavascript Even without css, it should still show as a link.

Comment: @David it comes out as a link without css because that's the standard behavior of `<a>` tags. I'm suggesting that the css page that holds the rules for `btn btn-info` is missing from your page and you should double check within the browser debug tools.

Comment: @David However, if you post your full code, then it will be easier to identify the problem and also if you can manage to give some screenshot of your problem

Comment: @RakibulIslam Im saying that it doesnt even come out as a standard link. It just comes out as text.

Comment: This is 100% a broken CSS issue.

Comment: What any of the “change this: …” answers so far should actually be changing it to, is this. http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php

Comment: @CBroe score farming ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. I have checked it in my localhost and it is working perfectly.

```
$url = 'https://www.facebook.com/';
echo '<a class="btn btn-info" href='.$url.'>Video Link</a>';
```

Please let me know if you have any further questions or any problem occurs.

Comment: That still comes out as plain text.

Comment: Can you try without variable like this: 

echo '<a class="btn btn-info" href="https://www.stackoverflow.com/">Video Link</a>';

Comment: still plain text.

Comment: Can you please give here the variable with initial data ?? for example I have used: $url = 'https://www.stackoverflow.com/';

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap the string you are contencating in double quotes, like this

`echo '<a class="btn btn-info" href="'.$url.'">Video Link</a>';`

Comment: its still coming out as text

Comment: Can you give me an example of what is stored in $url?

Comment: When you say it is coming out as text are you getting on the page <a class... as string not html?

Comment: Are you using a template engine on just php file?  Also are you also seeing echo as a string on the page?

Comment: its just 1 php file and im not seeing the echo bit

Comment: I don't see what could be the problem from the snippet you provided, can you post the whole file?

Answer (score 0):

href need to be wrapped up with href=""
try -----> href="'.$url.'"

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
echo '<a class="btn btn-info" href='.$url.'>Video Link</a>';
```

To this:

```
echo '<a class="btn btn-info" href="'.$url.'">Video Link</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use single quotes inside single quotes so you have to change your code to something like this

```
echo '<a class="btn btn-info" href="'.$url.'">Video Link</a>';
```